# Total number of stereoisomers of truxillic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, conformers

> Total number of stereoisomers of the compound will be:
>
> [image: truxillic acid]

This was a question asked in our mock test. I've tried by considering pseudo-chirality on the carbon atoms. But I don't know where to start.

I need help finding the different stereoisomers. It would be appreciated if you could draw the different isomers.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truxillic_acid) already has the answer. However, I strongly suggest you to try one more time before looking up the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]At first glance, not only does it seem like there are no stereogenic centres in truxillic acid, it is also highly symmetrical. However, if we consider different conformations of the chemically identical units (H, COOH or Ph), which give rise to different isomers, some carbons at the 4-membered ring can possibly become stereogenic.

Stereogenic centres are labelled with an asterisk: ε-truxillic acid and peri-truxillic acid do not have stereogenic carbon centres as their 4-membered ring carbons have chemically and conformationally identical neighbours.
It took me a while to get this.Thanks to @andselisk and wikipedia.